# Background service stops after application is closed in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin development. I have created one background service which is used to track user location. It's working properly till the time application is running/open. As application is closed/destroyed, my background service stops working. I have already spent so much time to find out the reason behind this issue. But bad luck.

```
[Service]
public class LocationTrackingService : Service, GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.IOnConnectionFailedListener, Android.Gms.Location.ILocationListener
{
    protected const string TAG = "Attendance Frag";
    protected const int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
    public const long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 20 * 1000;
    public const long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;
    protected const string KEY_REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES = "requesting-location-updates";
    protected const string KEY_LOCATION = "location";
    protected const string KEY_LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING = "last-updated-time-string";

    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    protected LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;


    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        BuildGoogleApiClient();
        CreateLocationRequest();

        Toast.MakeText(this, "OnCreate", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }

    protected void BuildGoogleApiClient()
    {
        Log.Info("AttendanceFrag", "Building GoogleApiClient");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .AddApi(LocationServices.API)
            .Build();
    }

    protected void CreateLocationRequest()
    {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.SetInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.SetFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.SetPriority(LocationRequest.PriorityHighAccuracy);
    }

    protected void BuildLocationSettingsRequest()
    {
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.AddLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        builder.SetAlwaysShow(true);
        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.Build();
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && !mGoogleApiClient.IsConnected)
            mGoogleApiClient.Connect();

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }


    protected async Task StartLocationUpdates()
    {
        await LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.RequestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient,
            mLocationRequest,
            this
        );
    }

    protected async Task StopLocationUpdates()
    {
        await LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.RemoveLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                this
            );
    }

    public async void OnConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
    {
        Log.Info(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");

        await StartLocationUpdates();
    }

    public void OnConnectionSuspended(int cause)
    {
        Log.Info(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    }

    public void OnConnectionFailed(Android.Gms.Common.ConnectionResult result)
    {
        Log.Info(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.ErrorCode);
    }

    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "OnLocationChanged", ToastLength.Short).Show();

    }

    public override async void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        Toast.MakeText(this, "OnDestroy", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null
            && mGoogleApiClient.IsConnected)
        {
            await StopLocationUpdates();
        }

        //Start GeoLocation Tracking Service again
        Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(RestartServiceReceiver));
        i.SetAction(RestartServiceReceiver.START_TRACKING);
        SendBroadcast(i);

    }
}
```

Please, help me

Comment: Have you registered the service in `manifest.xml` file?

Comment: As i know by defining [Service] , service is automatically registered into manifest.xml and note that service working fine till the time while application is open.After closing the application , service stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Start your service in a private process like this

```
[Service(Name = "com.xamarin.TimestampService", 
         Process=":timestampservice_process", 
         Exported=true)]
```

more info on running service in process [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/out-of-process-services/).
you can also register it as [foreground service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/foreground-services/) in that way they won't be stop by android and will show up in notification bar

Comment: Not working any more.Can you please do favor by posting any working/tested demo code which satisfy my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer but I think it can help others. I would like to make something clear for you that you are writing this service as a background service. Background service can not run for long. There are some limitation of background services in Android after Android 8.0 onwards. Android automatically kills background service of an app after some time.

See this https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

If you want to run a service for a long time then make the service Foreground Service. Please follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services for detailed knowledge of foreground service in Xamarin Forms.